# How can I replicate this functionality on my site?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, google-analytics

Recently, I was browsing through Reddit and found a site which is definitely using WordPress but is somehow loading Google Analytics from js-deliver.

I checked js-deliver for Analytics code but can't find it over there.

**What I am trying to achieve.**

I am trying to replicate this site's functionality. ( Please check the source code of https://gadgetraja.com/ ) {footer area}

Tools.pingdom.com shows that Google analytics take more than 500-milliseconds to load and then analytics loads a few additional resources. Totally it accounts for 700+ milliseconds on my site.

This site is somehow loading analytics within 51-milliseconds and maybe 100 more for other resources.

**See the image attached below.**

[image: tools.pingdom.com test result]

**I am trying to get better page speed scores** and as of now I am loading analytics on my site's head section and my site's grades are 72 for mobile and 90 for the desktop.

This site is loading analytics but still has 100% score on Mobile and Desktop.

I already tried to copy and paste the code and checked Analytics test visit but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I can't find any plugin, free or premium which can do this for me. I tried WordPress support but no one seems to be interested in this.

Can you guys please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you copied to try to get the version of GA Analytics code used at that site, but the particular file in question does appear to be public. Without really knowing how they set things up, I'd have to guess, but, in the meantime, you can try https://github.com/jehna/ga-lite

Comment: Also, IMO 72 mobile, 90 desktop is a fine score on GPSI, which I consider highly arbitrary in some respects, and almost a broken tool for many purposes.

Comment: @CKMacLeod Code is public. According to jsdeliver, they can only access public github repo. This site [gadgetraja](https://gadgetraja.com) is using this code: [link to source file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gadgetraja/official-site-statics@02/analytics.js)

Comment: @CKMacLeod, I am unable to paste the code in the comment area, says comment too long.